# Submit form after login authentification

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am passing a user and pass from a phone device to a .php page. This works fine. Then, I am taking this **username** and **password** and putting them into a function that checks into a database if they are correct. This works fine too. Next step is, if the authentification is correct, I need a form to be sent. To do so, I have tryed the following code which is not sending the form:

```
$login = \Fr\LS::login($user, $pass, false, false);
if($login === true){

//Some database stuff

$amount = "$price";
$id = "$num_fact";
$terminal = "01";
$moneda = "978";
$trans = "0";
$fuc = "335814141";
$urlOK = "https://www..com/.php";

$miObj = new RedsysAPI;
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT",$amount);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER",$id);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE",$fuc);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY",$moneda);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE",$trans);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL",$terminal);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL",$url);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLOK",$urlOK);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLKO",$urlKO);
$params = $miObj->createMerchantParameters();
$claveModuloAdmin = '';
$signature = $miObj->createMerchantSignature($claveModuloAdmin);
?>

<form name="form_tpv" id="form_tpv" style="display:none" action="https://sis-t.redsys.es:/sis/realizarPago" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="Ds_SignatureVersion" value="HMAC_SHA256_V1"/>
<input type="text" name="DS_MerchantParameters" value="<?php echo $params; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="Ds_Signature" value="<?php echo $signature; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Realizar Pago"/>
</form>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('form_tpv').submit();
}, 1000); 
</script>
```

What I tryed with the timeout is that when it loads (the form will be **loaded yet**), in one second the form would be sent.

ACTUALISATION:
This is how the code looks like now:

```
$login = \Fr\LS::login($user, $pass, false, false);
if($login === true){

$amount = "120";
$id = "gr";
$terminal = "01";
$moneda = "978";
$trans = "0";
$fuc = "335814141";
$urlOK = "https://www..com/.php";

$miObj = new RedsysAPI;
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT",$amount);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER",$id);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE",$fuc);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY",$moneda);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE",$trans);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL",$terminal);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL",$url);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLOK",$urlOK);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLKO",$urlKO);
$params = $miObj->createMerchantParameters();
$claveModuloAdmin = '';
$signature = $miObj->createMerchantSignature($claveModuloAdmin);
$url = 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:/sis/realizarPago';
$data = array(
   'Ds_SignatureVersion'=> 'HMAC_SHA256_V1',
  'DS_MerchantParameters' => $params,
      'Ds_Signature' => $signature
 );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//YOUR LINK IS HTTPS
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already has the values, don't use form in that way, it's wrong and will lead in a couple of issues. You don't needs user interaction with that form, so just call a function that relies on https://sis-t.redsys.es:/sis/realizarPago sending an array with all those values that you need as argument, which the backend will handle like you want.

Remove that html and javascript, seriously.

```
$login = \Fr\LS::login($user, $pass, false, false);
if($login === true){

//Some database stuff

$amount = "$price";
$id = "$num_fact";
$terminal = "01";
$moneda = "978";
$trans = "0";
$fuc = "335814141";
$urlOK = "https://www..com/.php";

$miObj = new RedsysAPI;
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_AMOUNT",$amount);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_ORDER",$id);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTCODE",$fuc);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_CURRENCY",$moneda);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TRANSACTIONTYPE",$trans);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_TERMINAL",$terminal);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL",$url);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLOK",$urlOK);
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_URLKO",$urlKO);
$params = $miObj->createMerchantParameters();
$claveModuloAdmin = '';
$signature = $miObj->createMerchantSignature($claveModuloAdmin);
if ($signature){
 $data = array(
       'Ds_SignatureVersion'=> 'HMAC_SHA256_V1',
      'DS_MerchantParameters' => $params,
          'Ds_Signature' => $signature
   );
  realizarPago($data);
 }
?>
```

You can use cURL to send data if the end of form is not your system:

```
$url = 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:/sis/realizarPago';
 $data = array(
       'Ds_SignatureVersion'=> 'HMAC_SHA256_V1',
      'DS_MerchantParameters' => $params,
          'Ds_Signature' => $signature
   );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//YOUR LINK IS HTTPS
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Observation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#110457

> Please everyone, stop setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false or 0. If
>   your PHP installation doesn't have an up-to-date CA root certificate
>   bundle, download the one at the curl website and save it on your
>   server:
>
> http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
>
> Then set a path to it in your php.ini file, e.g. on Windows:
>
> curl.cainfo=c:\php\cacert.pem
>
> Turning off CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER allows man in the middle (MITM)
>   attacks, which you don't want!

Comment: Thank you for you comment and complete answer. But how would you do to send all the `$data` in the array to "https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago"? I can't it

Comment: If the system is not the same, use cURL to send data, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit lost and trying to understand. Which piece of code should I use?

Comment: If the link of realizarPago is your code, use the first code, just use the function call to realizarPago routine like I showed. If the realizarPago is a system that's not yours and you dont have the code, use the second piece of code instead.

Comment: Ah no, it links to a tpv to do a payment. I have tryed the second code but it does not redirect to the page "https://sis-t.redsys.es:/sis/realizarPago"

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code I am using now. Can you see something missing?

Comment: The syntax seems ok, can var_dump the $result and show here?

Comment: If I take your code outside the `if($login===true){`
Then, it shows error 500: Internal server error of my domain, not the one I want to send the variables and redirect to